# How to Install Django with command sudo

Tags: django

I want to install django into my CentOS virtual machine. When I search on the Internet for the solutions, I found tutorial page like this image of downloading command

[image]

But I when I type the command sudo, and then type Linux virtual machine password, it does not work.

Image of sudo error:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: How did you create your virtual machine and why aren't you installing django with pip?

Comment: ObXKCD: https://xkcd.com/838/ (not the one you think)

Answer (score 1):

To install Django on CentOS system, you have to process like that :

**Step 1 : Update your system**

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum update -y && sudo reboot
```

**Step 2 : Install pip and dependencies**

```
sudo yum install python-devel python-setuptools python-pip
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

**Step 3 : Install virtualenv and Django inside**

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
source ~/djangoenv/bin/activate
```

You will obtain something like :

```
(djangoenv) [user@hostname ~]$
```

**Step 4 : Install Django**

```
pip install django
#or particular version X.X
pip install django==X.X
```

**Step 5 : Create your project**

```
cd ~
django-admin startproject myproject
```

**Step 6 : Runserver**

```
cd myproject/
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that your username `sv` is not in the sudo user list. You should ask you sysadmin to add that user to sudo user list. or you can try this 
`usermod` command like `usermod -aG groupname username`. Refer this (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sudo-user-on-centos-quickstart)

You should try a different strategy to install. Two useful links are as follows:

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-centos-7
2. https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-django-on-centos-7

Answer (score 0):

Use yum package manager to download and install Django (although it recommended to work in env):

```
sudo yum install python-django
```

Test the installation:

```
django-admin --version
```